# Hashbytes in SQL returning a differnet value to all other hashers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I've been looking at having fields store user passwords as hashes, For this the password hash is going to be stored into the database within a column marked as binary.

Then the insert for the user is the following:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[Users] (email, passwordHash)
        VALUES('email...', HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', TRIM('Password'))
```

This the adds a user to my "Users" table and then displays the password hash as '0x32519F3C7685A1B....'.

However when I check a SHA512 hash for 'Password' online and within my program it returns the SHA512 hash of '0xE6C83B82...'

Does anyone know what I'm missing with this? I added in the TRIM (having tried RTRIM also) incase there was a white space issue anywhere but it returns the same result.

Within my program (VB.Net to get used to it all again) is the following for the hashing:

```
Public Function getHash(strToHash As String) As String
        Dim sha512 As SHA512 = SHA512Managed.Create()
        Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strToHash)
        Dim hash As Byte() = sha512.ComputeHash(bytes)
        Dim strResult As New StringBuilder()

        For i As Integer = 0 To hash.Length - 1
            strResult.Append(hash(i).ToString("X2"))
        Next

        MsgBox(strResult.ToString)
```

Comment: You're encoding the string as UTF-8. SQL Server is encoding it as whatever the encoding is as implied by your default collation (typically a `Latin1` variant, which corresponds more or less to Windows-1252). If you need consistent results, use `N'Password'` to hash big-endian Unicode. From 2019 onwards SQL Server supports UTF-8, so that `SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'Password' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC_UTF8)` will give you back the same hash.

Comment: Thanks for that, however even with that in this column is still displaying the "0x3E519..." value. That is using it as "INSERT INTO dbo.[Users] ( email, passwordHash)
        VALUES('Email..', HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', TRIM('Password') COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC_UTF8))"

Comment: That seems wildly improbable, since that's definitely not what that expression returns. [Proof](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=40c50bf8a88155b0ed98044e4182d222). Check your assumptions on what's actually executing and where.

Comment: Thank you, sorry about that, I just wiped the whole table and re-created it all and it is now working as intended. Sorry once again.

Comment: Note that requiring UTF-8 does limit you to SQL Server 2019 or later. Hashing `N'Password'` (and/or using an `NVARCHAR` parameter) and using `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` in your code instead will work on all versions of SQL Server 2012 onwards. This may not be a consideration in your setup, but still.

Comment: Thank you, I was only using UTF-8 as you never know what people may want to set their password as.  I will have a look into your suggestion